# How to bulk add a new category to multiple products

Tags: category

Is there a way to bulk add a new category to multiple products in Enterprise?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and also in Community. Just go to Catalog > Categories, select your category and then the tab "Category Products". Then select all the products you want to add and save the category.

Comment: Thanks Simon, but I have a list of over 2000 products of a possible 30000 so I am looking to be able to bulk upload. Perhaps there is an extension?